# how do i change the color to individual body parts?

Tags: mesh, materials

[image][image]i am following the complete beginners guide 2.8 on youtube but when he changes the color of the guys legs and hands, on mine it is all linked to the same color and i dont know how to fix it. top picture is the video and bottom is what i did. first time ever on blender

Comment: Hi and welcome. It's hard to tell without knowing the video and more details of your scene. Feel free to add a screenshot. One reason can be that you are in Solid view mode or you have only 1 material.

Comment: hi I edited the post and posted a picture of what i have and what the video has

Comment: Hi Steve.  Your issue is just a misunderstanding of materials, material slots, and assignments.  I think it's very common as a beginner because, among other things, the terminology is confusing.  I think this tutorial will help you here, your specific issue appears to be this:  https://youtu.be/nBdGm_d_8XE?t=886

Comment: FYI the first material *slot* on your hands is the one that is currently assigned